# How to shorten a long path that points to the root of a hard drive?

Tags: disk, disk-usage

I am looking for something that I can type to shorten a long path. This path happens to point to a separate hard drive, and I'm hoping that will help.

Background

1. Our company has provided us with Ubuntu machines containing a system drive and a larger, faster work drive.
2. Company policy says that all software development (meaning compiling of executable code, but *not* all work) must be done in a specific folder. Our anti-virus software has been configured not to block or quarantine changing executable files within a particular directory structure. Unfortunately (and I'm not sure I follow the details of this part) in order to prevent malware from infecting these whitelisted directories, they are multiple levels deep. In other words, all development work must be done at the end of an arbitrarily long path.
3. I have successfully mounted the large hard drive at the path specified by the policy. In other words, the long and arbitrary path points to what (in DOS) I would call the root of the drive.

What I want

- To be able to type `cd foo` and have the OS perform `cd /my/company/arbitrary/path`
- To be able to use other Linux commands for copying / accessing files and get a similar substitution.
- Ideally, though this is not essential, I would like the command prompt to display the shortened form of the path.

My question

- If I use a "symbolic link" or "soft link" to get the OS to perform this substitution automatically, will this meet my needs, or does it have limitations that might affect my workflow down the line? (Reminder: not all my work will be done on this drive.)
- Is there a smarter way of doing this? Can I take advantage of the fact that the path actually "points to" the mount point (or "root") of the physical device?
- Are there additional tricks I can perform to shorten the command prompt to show the user-friendly shorter version of the current working directory when I'm within the work area?

Comment: Please ask your command prompt questions separately since the answer will depend on exactly how your `PS1` variable is set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual ways of dealing with this are:

1. Make a symlink in your local directory

   ```
    ln -s /very/long/path/to/some/folder/hidden/deep/in/the/file/system ~/foo
   ```

   You can now do `cd foo` from your local directory and that will take you to `/very/long/path/to/some/folder/hidden/deep/in/the/file/system`. Depending on how your system is set up, you may have to use `cd -P foo` for your setup to recognize that you are in `/very/long/path/to/some/folder/hidden/deep.in/the/file/system` and not in `~/foo`. To illustrate:

   ```
    $ ls -l foo
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 terdon terdon 61 Jan  7 14:46 foo -> /very/long/path/to/some/folder/hidden/deep/in/the/file/system
    $ cd foo
    $ pwd
    /home/terdon/foo
   ```

   Now, do the same thing but with `cd -P`:

   ```
   $ cd -P foo
   $ pwd
   /very/long/path/to/some/folder/hidden/deep/in/the/file/system
   ```
2. Make an alias for the command. Open your shell's config file (use `~/.bashrc` if you are using `bash`) and add this line:

   ```
    alias cdfoo='cd /very/long/path/to/some/folder/hidden/deep.in/the/file/system'
   ```

   Then, save the file, open a new terminal, and run `cdfoo`. That will take you straight to `/very/long/path/to/some/folder/hidden/deep.in/the/file/system`.
3. Store the name in a variable. Open your `~/.profile` file (or `~/.bash_profile` if that file already exists and you are using `bash`) and add this line:

   ```
   foo="/very/long/path/to/some/folder/hidden/deep/in/the/file/system"
   ```

   Now, either log out and log back in or run `. ~/.profile` to read the new variable definition. From now on, you will be able to do `cd $foo` and move to the target directory. Note that, if your path contains spaces or any other whitespace or globbing characters, you should quote the variable: `cd "$foo"`.

Of the three choices above, the first (symlink) and the third (variable) let you do everything you want. With a symlink, you can `cd foo` and `cp bar/file foo/` and everything else. What will be displayed in your prompt when you `cd` into it will depend on how your prompt is set up.

Answer (score 0):

You could `foo="/my/company/arbitrary/path"` then `cd "$foo"` etc. You can miss the quotes out for ease of typing if there ate no spaces in the path.